# iOS - CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification notification details discreapencies

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to get the latest changes in iPhone contact book

I am about to integrate Contacts Framework in my iOS app and would like to get notified when contact is changed (added/edit fields in the contact) externally (by other app or by user). I have found the **CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification** and wonder if it will bring in meaningful form what exactly has changed in the contact card and/or information on which contact was changed.

Can't find it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification does not give the changes. So if you have some cached contacts, you have to refetch them when the notification comes.

```
-(void)registerForCNContactStoreDidChangeNotification {
   if (!self.hasRegisteredForNotifications) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(storeDidChange:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
        self.hasRegisteredForNotifications = YES;
   }
}

- (void)deviceContactsDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
// notification.userInfo can be nil

// need to fetch all contacts with enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest to get all contacts or
// refresh the cached contacts with unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate
}
```

[Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore?language=objc)

> If you cache the fetched contacts, groups, or containers, you need to refetch these objects (and release the old cached objects) when CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification is posted.

Comment: Thanks @coconata. Besides re-syncing all of the contacts are you aware of any workarounds, please?

Comment: unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate allows fetching the only necessary contacts